# Python (3.7+) multiprocessing: replace Pipe connection between master and workers with asyncio for IO concurrency

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

Suppose we have a following toy version of master-worker pipeline to parallel data collection

```
# pip install gym
import gym
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

def worker(master_conn, worker_conn):
    master_conn.close()

    env = gym.make('Pendulum-v0')
    env.reset()

    while True:
        cmd, data = worker_conn.recv()

        if cmd == 'close':
            worker_conn.close()
            break
        elif cmd == 'step':
            results = env.step(data)
            worker_conn.send(results)

class Master(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.master_conns, self.worker_conns = zip(*[Pipe() for _ in range(10)])
        self.list_process = [Process(target=worker, args=[master_conn, worker_conn], daemon=True) 
                             for master_conn, worker_conn in zip(self.master_conns, self.worker_conns)]
        [p.start() for p in self.list_process]
        [worker_conn.close() for worker_conn in self.worker_conns]

    def go(self, actions):
        [master_conn.send(['step', action]) for master_conn, action in zip(self.master_conns, actions)]
        results = [master_conn.recv() for master_conn in self.master_conns]

        return results

    def close(self):
        [master_conn.send(['close', None]) for master_conn in self.master_conns]
        [p.join() for p in self.list_process]

master = Master()
l = []
T = 1000
for t in range(T):
    actions = np.random.rand(10, 1)
    results = master.go(actions)
    l.append(len(results))

sum(l)
```

Because of the Pipe connections between master each worker, for every time step, we have to send a command to the worker through the Pipe, and the worker sends back the results. We need to do this for a long horizon. This will be sometimes a bit slow due to frequent communications.

Therefore, I am wondering if by using latest Python feature asyncio combined with Process to replace Pipe, could it be potentially speedup due to IO concurrency, if I understand its functionality correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Multiprocessing module has already a solution for parallel task processing: [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.pool.Pool)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:         # start 4 worker processes
        print(pool.map(f, range(10)))       # prints "[0, 1, 4,..., 81]"
```

You can achieve the same using [`multiprocessing.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.Queue). I believe that's how `pool.map()` is implemented internally.

So, what's the difference between [`multiprocessing.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.Queue) and [`multiprocessing.Pipe`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.Pipe)? `Queue` is just a `Pipe` plus some locking mechanism. Therefore multiple worker processes can share just a single `Queue` (or rather 2 - one for commands, one for results), but with `Pipe` each process would need it's own `Pipe` (or a pair of, or a duplex one), exactly how you are doing it now.

The only disadvantage of `Queue` is performance - because all processes share one queue mutex it doesn't scale well for many processes. To be sure it can handle tens of thousands items/s I would choose `Pipe`, but for classic parallel task processing use case I think `Queue` or just `Pool.map()` could be OK because they are much easier to use. (Managing processes can be tricky and asyncio doesn't make it easier either.)

Hope that helps, I'm aware that I've answered a bit different question than you've asked :)